# Alienware M17X switched to discrete only, now only get a black screen after windows logo

Tags: windows-7, boot, graphics-card

There's a button on this laptop which switches to discrete graphics only (labelled I/D GFX) and it asks to reboot the machine to take effect.

After the windows boot logo, the screen goes black and the windows login screen chime can be heard.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that it's impossible to get into any recovery mode with Windows, no hardware faults present.

The solution is quite old school, you'll need to remove the CMOS cell battery to reset the BIOS.

Follow these instructions: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN131110/EN

You will simply need to remove and replace the battery.

Then boot the device and you'll see your integrated graphics card has been restored.

(Side note: I booted the device without a CMO